# Django writable nested serializers, create method not working

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a nested serializer, the create method does not work. I have searched over the internet and no method worked for me. The most popular one is the one listed below.

models.py

```py
class Displays(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32,
                          default=generate_uuid)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)


class OrdersDj(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32,
                          default=generate_uuid)

class AdsDj(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32,
                          default=generate_uuid)
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        OrdersDj, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
    display = models.ForeignKey(
        Displays, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class DisplaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Displays
        fields = "__all__"

class AdsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    display = DisplaySerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("validated_data", validated_data)
        display_id = validated_data.pop('display')
        display = Displays.objects.get(id=display_id)
        ad = Displays.objects.create(display=display, **validated_data)
        return ad

    class Meta:
        model = Ads
        fields = "__all__"


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ads = AdsSerializer(source="adsdj_set", many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.pop('adsdj_set')
        order = Orders.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return order

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```
class AdsCreate(APIView):

    def put(self, request):
        print('request.data', request.data)
        serializer = serializers.AdsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print('serializer.data > serializer.valid', serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        print('serializer.errors > serializer.invalid', serializer.errors)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

print outs

```
request.data <QueryDict: {'order': ['18bb2225cf6e407a943f2941072d06de'], 'display': ['91'], 'firstday': ['2021-12-4'], 'lastday': ['2021-12-21'], 'duration': ['17'], 'filetype': ['image/png'], 'originalname': ['Picture1.png'], 'price': ['2550'], 'status': ['0'], 'filehash': ['not available yet'], 'orderByNum': ['-1'], 'imgWidth': ['1061'], 'imgHeight': ['708'], 'image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: Picture1.png (image/png)>]}>

serializer.errors > serializer.invalid {'display': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

I am giving the `display` field to the serializer that is the id of the display. In the create method I find that display and reference it in the new `ad` object. The display field is present in the `request.data` and passed to the serializer, the serializer complains that the `display` field is not present.

One version of sending json data

```json
{"order":"18bb2225cf6e407a943f2941072d06de","display":{"id":91},"firstday":"2021-12-5","lastday":"2021-12-15","duration":11,"image":{},"filetype":"image/png","originalname":"Picture1.png","price":1650,"status":0,"filehash":"not available yet","orderByNum":-1,"imgWidth":1061,"imgHeight":708}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using different serializers for creation and representation.

```
class AdsCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ads
        fields = "__all__"
```

```
class AdsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    display = DisplaySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Ads
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: When I create a new ad, I want to return the created ad with the display representation. This way, the display is null when the ad is created.

Comment: Then you will have to create a nested writable serializer.

Answer (score -1):

For `display` field, `AdsSerializer` expects the following structure;

```
"display": {"id": 91}
```

whereas you send this;

```
"display": 91
```

Comment: `display[id]': ['91']` in `request.data` and the same error is thrown

Comment: Can you show the `Display Serializer` ?

Comment: Can you share the request body you sent in JSON format?

Comment: @Rvector check the updated question